# imported module.submodule namespaces interfering with eachother

Tags: python-3.2

So I'm pretty deep into making a custom job/process custom manager module, and when i got to integrating it I came across an interaction I hadn't seen before with modules and namespaces.

Code speaks better than words:

So there are two slightly different scripts:

test1:

```
import jobManager

jobManager.jobMap = {'test1':'test123'}
```

AND test2:

```
import jobManager

jobManager.jobMap = {'test2':'test222'}
```

Top Level Script:

```
import test1
import test2

print(test1.jobManager.jobMap)
print(test2.jobManager.jobMap)
```

So when I run the top level script it prints:

```
{'test2':'test222'}
{'test2':'test222'}
```

But my expected output is:

```
{'test1':'test123'}
{'test2':'test222'}
```

Is this just a case where test1.jobManager and test2.jobManager are actually the same namespace? Is there a way to keep them separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this just a case where test1.jobManager and test2.jobManager are actually the same namespace?

Yes.

> Is there a way to keep them separate?

Not without creating another module.

Comment: So would a workaround be to wrap it all in a class, and initialize it inside of each of the relevant modules? Or is there some other way?

Comment: I'm surprised it is something that I haven't come across before, is it just a case where using global variables can get messy? Or are there other pit falls i should watch out for?

Comment: If you multiple independent instances of behavior then a class is the way to go. The other pitfall to watch out for is when a module can be found multiple ways via `sys.path`; it is possible to import the same module multiple different ways, *but this is degenerate behavior and should not be used to "solve" the issue above*.